# Complement of the Cantor Set

Tags: elementary-set-theory

The Cantor Set denoted by $C$, is defined in *Definition* $\,1.1\,$.

My initial question is how would the complement of the Cantor Set be formulated?

$$\text{Definition }\; 1.1:\quad C: = \bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty}C_n$$

Comment: $C^{\complement} = \cup_{n=1}^\infty C_n^{\complement}$ by DeMorgan's law. Is there something more specific that you were looking for, perhaps?

Comment: I also want to ask, does the Complement of the Cantor Set still hold it's same properties I apologize for the dumb question, I didn't realize the major theorem that could be applied to this scenario to justify the initial conclusion I had.

Comment: What are the same properties? The Cantor set has measure zero, so its complement will obviously have measure one. The Cantor set is meager, so obviously its complement will be comeager.

Comment: I'm initially asking this to verify an idea that I had: since the complement of the cantor set was taken it would be safe to assume that all defined property's for the Cantor Set are now the converse

Comment: As long as you don't say what the "defined properties" you have in mind are, it will be hard to help. Also say what exactly is the converse for these defined properties?

Comment: The one property that I was looking at was the notion of closure, for the Cantor Set I assumed since the complement was taken that the Cantor Set would be open.

Answer (score 1):

Use DeMorgan:

$$C' = (\bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty}C_n)' = \bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}C_n'$$